# Removing outer parenthesis in a diagram

Tags: matrices, parenthesis

When I try to remove the outer brackets in the following diagram, by removing the first occurrence of `\begin{pmatrix}` and the last occurrence of `\end{pmatrix}` I get the error `misplaced alignment tab character &`. I cannot see which tab character is causing the problem and why it is causing the problem. How can I remove the outer parentheses without incurring this problem, and preserving all other properties as is, except for perhaps making the gap between rows slightly smaller. I have used `\\ \\` below, but this gap is too big, whilst `\\` is too small.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,color, graphicx, amsfonts, braket}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[\begin{pmatrix}\begin{matrix} \begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array} \\ \\ \text{John} \\ \\ \cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ saw\ } \end{matrix} &
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array}     & \begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array}  \\  \\ 
\text{saw}         & \text{Mary}\\ \\
\cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ a\ } & \cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ b\ }
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
\]


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `pmatrix` (which automatically add a pair of brackets) to `matrix`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,color, graphicx, amsfonts, braket}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[\begin{matrix}\begin{matrix} \begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array} \\ \\ \text{John} \\ \\ \cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ saw\ } \end{matrix} &
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array}     & \begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array}  \\  \\ 
\text{saw}         & \text{Mary}\\ \\
\cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ a\ } & \cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ b\ }
\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
\]


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid using double `\\`s. You always have `\\[]`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,color, graphicx, amsfonts, braket}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[\begin{matrix}\begin{matrix} \begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array} \\[2ex] \text{John} \\ \cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ saw\ } \end{matrix} &
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array}     & \begin{array}{c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cfrac{\ t \ }{\ e \to e \to t \ }}
\end{array}  \\[2ex] 
\text{saw}         & \text{Mary}\\
\cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ a\ } & \cfrac{\ \operatorname{[\;]}\ }{\ b\ }
\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
\]


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. The other thing I wanted to know was how to get the space between each row slightly less. I had `\\` before and in the above it is `\\ \\`. But this is slightly too big, whilst `\\` is too small.

Comment: I have edited my question slightly to incorporate this.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't produce enough space between the top two rows. Can I use `0.5ex`?

Comment: @user65526 Look at my edited answer. I used the default spacing in the space between row 2 and row 3, but `\\[2ex]` between row 1 and row 2. In fact, you can add anything between `[` and `]`, for example `\\[1cm]`, even negative numbers can be added.

Comment: @user65526 Do you have any questions?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my question again.

Comment: I have just re-edited my question.

Comment: @user65526 It is an interesting question, however it is not really related to this question IMHO. I think you should ask a new question, so that I and others can have some look.

Comment: I will ask a separate question, then, and I will click your answer here as the accepted answer.

Comment: @user65526 and surely I will upvote that.

Comment: Just asked it as a separate question.